# GET method PHP for accessing and displaying Information from web services

Tags: php, curl

I wish to know how to pass a variable in the http header field? I tried with this code and it returns me `status 500 error`.

```
echo $token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'X-Auth-Token: $token'));
```

This is the error that I am receiving:

> {"timestamp":1436349947368,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server
>   Error","exception":"java.lang.RuntimeException","message":"org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException:
>   user name not found","path":"/api/customers/new"}

I have stored the token received from the web service in $token, can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Looking forward for your response,

Thank you

Comment: As said in the error, the Java back-end didn't find the username. You'll need to check where it looks for the username and what is used in the search.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you use a single quotation mark, but want to pass the token var.

Should be:

```
echo $token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
"X-Auth-Token: $token"));
```

Comment: Hello freytag....Tried that...now it is giving me an error of: {"timestamp":1436353851016,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/api/customers/new"}

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
$_SESSION["Token"]=$token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
"Content-Type: application/json",                                                                                
"X-Auth-Token: " . $_SESSION["Token"]));
```

And it is working fine now......

Thanks